# OpenType Kern Arabic

Tags: c++, arabic, opentype

I'm developing my own layout engine.But I meet the kern problem of the OpenType Font processing in arabic.Before asking this question,I confirm arial.ttf in windows 8 that contain arabic char.As you know,sometimes some arabic char can connected as one char.So after I read OpenType Specification,I tried to analysis the kern information in GPOS.Unfortunately it seems don't contain the kern information.Then I tried to use fontforge to get the information of arial.ttf,I have adoubt about the pairset kerning.
When I choose the option of FreeType,the information showed below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q2N0.jpg)
When I don't choose the option of Freetype,the information showed below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi06S.jpg)

You can know that the two char isn't connected as one char if you don't choose the option of freetype.My question is how to adjust the distance of this two chars,so the two char can connect as one char.
When I start to program,I meet the same question.This is my program show:
[enter image description here][3]

Is there anyone know how to adjust the distance between two char?I confirm that the GPOS table don't contain the kern offset between this two char.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: This is a question much better asked over on http://typedrawers.com

Answer (score 0):

GPOS is a positioning table. I guess you want to replace as sequence of chars for one alternative (ligature). Therefore you need to use the GSUB table. It handles substitutions. Eg: `sub f i by f_i;`

Comment: I need connect two char as one.Before GPOS,I had mapping them through GSUB.The real question is that there is a gap between two char,what can I do to reduce the gap and make them displayed in word 2013.